# Using either aparte or separado(a)

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

The expression in English,
"These breads [this bread] in a separate bag please."

Normally I'd say,

> Por favor, estos panes en una bolsa (de papel) separada

Google translate used apartar

> ..... bolsa (de papel) aparte

The issue is in English the literal translation of apartar would be weird in this context.
Which is commonly used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (**Put**) These breads in a separate bag, please.

En estos casos se usan las conjugaciones del modo **imperativo**. La forma más formal de traducir la frase consiste en no omitir el verbo:

> Por favor, **[usted] ponga / [ustedes] pongan / [vos] poné / [tú] pon** estos panes en una bolsa separada.

Como podés ver, la persona del verbo depende del pronombre que quieras usar. Sin embargo, casi nunca se escribe ni se pronuncia el pronombre cuando es un imperativo.

Por supuesto, se puede omitir el verbo, con lo cual la expresión queda más informal:

> Estos panes en una bolsa separada, por favor.

Como ves, en este caso escribí el ‘por favor’ al final. Es solamente un detalle estético para que suene mejor.

**Posdata**: ‘bolsa de papel separada’ y ‘bolsa de papel aparte’ son sinónimos, se pueden usar cualquiera de las dos.

Comment: Gracias es muy útil. Google aparece mal. Solo estoy aprendiendo el "modo imperativo" entonces lo omití.

Comment: @M__ Cuidado, ahora caigo en que google no se equivocó...